# How to handle the redirect during a POST Request?

Tags: javascript, http, post, xmlhttprequest

I am making a POST request from "request" npm module. As mentioned in the docs, redirect is getting handled by the module. However I am not able to access the page content in the callback function.

During a normal POST request, one can access the content of the page returned through the body variable. Can someone tell how to access this content and after doing some validation on this content make another POST call ?

Comment: The interface doesn't let you see the response that told you to redirect. If the redirect pointed you to a different origin that doesn't have _CORS_, you then would also get a security error (I believe) so again not be able to see the the response

Comment: [EDIT]Thanks Paul. I saw your comment after posting mine. The redirect url also has the same origin. So I was not getting security error. It was just that I had to enable some option in the request module[EDIT].

I found the solution to this problem. I used the request npm module. Make sure you read through the documentation and read about follow redirects and jar option.